# Specifying Github branch in Cartfile

Tags: github, xcode9, eureka-forms

Specifically, from Eureka. I am trying to use this branch:
https://github.com/xmartlabs/Eureka/tree/feature/Xcode9-Swift3_2
as the master branch is failing to build.

This was my Cartfile for the master:
github "xmartlabs/Eureka" ~> 3.0.0

I have tried to specify the XCode9 (as that is what I am using) branch with:
github "xmartlabs/Eureka" "/tree/feature/Xcode9-Swift3_2" ,
github "xmartlabs/Eureka" "/feature/Xcode9-Swift3_2",
and
github "xmartlabs/Eureka" "/Xcode9-Swift3_2".

At this point am just guessing.

Any help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are almost there. No need for slash (/). Following should work:

```
github "xmartlabs/Eureka" "feature/Xcode9-Swift3_2"
```